# extra white space appear in code snippet area in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, code-snippets

I am using ckeditor's code snippet pluggin.Problem is when in put code in the window everything is ok in chrome ,but when i put it in editor  a lot of white space appears.And in firefox white space appears both in snippet window and editor.How i can solve this? i want something like SO's code snippet's auto indentation

i tried the following code.but not helping me much:

```
 CKEDITOR.addCss( 'body {word-break:break-all;}' );

        CKEDITOR.addCss('code{font-size:14px;}');
        CKEDITOR.addCss('code{white-space:pre-wrap}');
```

snippet window:

[image]

after adding the code snippet to the editor:

[image]

Comment: have you filed a bug issue? i'm sure people involved in the project can find the answer quicker.

Comment: can't post anything on ckeditor forum.it' operated readonly mode.